# googlesheet script question about mapping specific range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this onEdit function that goes over the sheet, looks at the cell value under NAME column, finds its position in another cell under LIST column and outputs this position in the POSITION column.
I am trying to find a way to limit this in a specific range, more specifically to exclude the 1st row (row 1) from this indexing, since if i add a row above the LIST, NAME and POSITION the function fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`.

Heres my function -

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); 

function onEdit() {
  
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();

  if( r.getColumn() > 7 ) {
    
    let idx = {};
    hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
    let vO1 = vs.map((r, i) => {
      var tes = [r[idx['LIST']].toString().split(',').indexOf( r[idx['NAME']] ) +1]
      return (tes == 0) ? [''] : tes;
    });
    sh.getRange(2, idx['POSITION'] + 1, vO1.length, vO1[0].length).setValues(vO1); 
}
}
```

Comment: How about just doing it for the row that has been edited?

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of `sheet1`? Also, it would be helpful if you could provide the logs of `hA`, `vs` and `r[idx['LIST']]`. Besides, if there is any sheet(s) apart from `sheet1`, `sheet1` maybe updated unexpectedly.

Comment: Here's an example sheet1 - https://imgur.com/a/tzgnVnM - for example i've added the header, and changed the 'dog' under NAME from 'mouse', yet the cells dont update.
I tried to add some conditions for r.getRow() > 1, but it still seems the mapping is taking the entire sheet range and indexing it

Comment: `hA` is `['header', '', '']`, so `idx['LIST']` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 1 row before labels:

```js
const [header, hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Alternative:

```js
const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
values.shift();
const [hA, ...vs] = values;
```

---

Mutiple rows (specify `labelRow`):

```js
const labelRow = 2;
const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
const [hA, ...vs] = values.slice(labelRow - 1);
```

Alternative:

```js
const labelRow = 2;
const rows = sh.getLastRow() - labelRow + 1;
const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getRange(label, 1, rows, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

---

There are bugs on your code.

`return (tes == 0) ? [''] : tes;` should be:

```js
      return (tes == [0]) ? [''] : tes;
```

`sh.getRange(2, idx['POSITION'] + 1, vO1.length, vO1[0].length).setValues(vO1);` should be (make sure to define `labelRow`):

```
    sh.getRange(labelRow + 1, idx['POSITION'] + 1, vO1.length, vO1[0].length).setValues(vO1);
```

Comment: header should be a variable in here or a string? what should i put in if my 'header' cell is actually a blank cell? and what should i do if i have other rows that do not have values in them above the LIST, NAME, POSITION rows? like here https://imgur.com/a/w2Ld1fk

Comment: Updated, please check. `header` is a variable used to store and exclude the header row. A blank row before data would also be included in `getDataRange`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so far, i've tried all the above and when i run the function i get an error `Exception: The starting column of the range is too small.`

Comment: I have pointed out the bugs in your code. However, they should not relate to your error. Is there any spaces after `POSITION` cell? Please provide the log of `idx`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and suggestions, i cleaned up the code and did it from scratch with your suggestions and it seems to work now!